# Failed to instantiate on or more classes Launcher3 open-source

Tags: android

I am using the [open-source of launcher3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/), in `launcher.xml` the error: `Failed to instantiate on or more classes`

```
The following classes could not be instantiated

-com.android.launcher3.Hotseat (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.DeleteDropTarget (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.InfoDropTarget (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.Workspace (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.CellLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.Pageindicators.PageIndicatorLinecaret (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
-com.android.launcher3.UninstallDropTarget (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown IDE

If this in an unexpected error you can try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout

Exception Details
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost
(Copy stack to clipboard)
```

and `Layout fidelity warning` are appearing (disabling the IDE for showing the layout)

```
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:

-Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported (Ignore for this session)
```

I have tried: clearing cache, refreshing the layout, Invalidate cache and restart, ensuring manually of the existence to the classes by opening them

Any needed additional info are welcomed for sure

Thanks in advance

Comment: as we have no answer I have reported it to google with the link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37823026, so, please please take the issue as yours and star it to get notice to google faster